# How to implement collapsable/expandable items in a list with Epoxy?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, epoxy, epoxy-modelview

How properly to implement collapsing/expanding items using [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) Android library?
I went through the [wiki](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/wiki) and [sample app](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/wiki/Sample-App) and couldn't find any example or explanation how exactly implement such behaviour in the list?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to implement one?  Does your recycler view jump up once item is expanded?

Comment: Yes i did I just request model build in the controller when need to collapse or expand by visible/gone views in the layout and recycle view do for me by default   collapsable/expandable animation, you can even provide your custom layout animation if you not contented with default one.